# ERROR: General packaging failure -- When packaging an MSI using devenv.com

Tags: windows-installer, devenv

I have a Visual studio C# solution for deploying a regression test setup. The solution contains class library, Console Application and deployment (.vdproj) projects. The output of Class Library and Console Application projects are added as files to be packaged in the deployment project. There is one project (lets call it content.csproj) in the solution which holds all the 'content' files (test scripts, test input files, test config files etc.). Content files are files which are not compiled when the solution is built. Rather, these files are merely copied to the output directory.
The content of content.csproj is also added as the list of files to be packaged.
The number files that are part of the content.csproj has grown to an extremely large level approx 10,000 files or even more.
At one point the MSI packaging started to fail when packaging the contents of the content.csproj with the error,

ERROR: General packaging failure

ERROR: Unrecoverable build error

I guess this is due to the large number of files in the content.csproj
Can someone explain the exact reason for seeing such error? 
I would appreciate if someone could guide me how the deployment project should be created and configured to avoid this scenario again.

What is the best way to create MSI package when there are extremely large number of files to be packaged?

Details:

I am using devenv.com that comes with the installation of Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0

Thanks,

Balaji